# 'Did 'the' in 'the which' mean anything?' : Why closed as 'Language-specific'?

Tags: discussion

[Did 'the' in 'the which' mean anything?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17505/did-the-in-the-which-mean-anything) references more than 1 language.

I am stupefied that the above would be closed as Language-specific, whereas [Why does French use “be” as the auxiliary for a few verbs?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17534/why-does-french-use-be-as-the-auxiliary-for-a-few-verbs) and [Why did French survive in Canada while being far from France, while other languages didn't (Arabic in Malta, Dutch in South Africa)](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17529/why-did-french-survive-in-canda-while-being-far-from-france-while-other-languag) are not?

Please tell me if I erred, but I feel that some users are closing my questions because of personal antipathy or dislike against me? If so, I am sorry for irritating or offending anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reopened the question. Since Jlaweler has answered it already, you may want to copy-paste that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: +1. Thank you for your benevolence. Before I do so, I will message Prof Lawler because he may wish to do this himself.